# DISM Error code 11 when converting Windows 10 install.esd to wim

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, dism

I downloaded Windows 10 ISO file from Media Creation Tool that made by Microsoft. I wanna edit install.esd and for this I need to convert it to install.wim. I tried to do it with DISM but I got one error:

> `Error: 11 An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

I use Windows 7 for this. I tried to run PowerShell as Administrator but this not helped too.

Here is the [dism.log](https://pastebin.pl/view/41bad06c) file.

Comment: Dism in windows 7 is very limited, try doing it on a w10 PC if you have access.

Comment: Is there another way? for example:Make it from phone?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You can install Windows 10 from the MCL download by running Setup in the downloaded ISO file.

Comment: I am low end pc user and I need to use Windows 10 for work. I wanna delete some elements like Cortana(I don't use it) and Xbox gaming and etc. That is why I need wim file

Comment: https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-easily-convert-install-esd-to-install-wim/

Comment: You can install Windows 10 normally and not use apps not needed. Cortana (even if not used) is part of Search and should not be removed.  XBOX and other apps can be quickly uninstalled in Settings, Apps.  Apps uninstalls work fine.

Comment: @Moab It does same commands like `DISM /Get-WimInfo /wimfile:install.esd` and `DISM /export-image /sourceimagefile:install.esd /sourceindex:1 /destinationimagefile:install.wim /compress:max /checkintegrity`

Comment: @John ,my system requirements are really low. CPU: Intel Pentium E5300, GPU:Nvidia GeForce 7300 GS Ram:2GB. So,I need to remove some things for better performance.

Comment: You may be making this much more difficult than it needs to be. Think through the installation process I posted.. You can easily uninstall items which can be removed. My system runs less that 5% CPU more than 95% of the time.

Comment: Any other solutions or ways?

Comment: Your computer is very low end as you said and likely has a 5400-rpm hard drive. So it will be very slow with Windows 7 or 10. Is it at all feasible to get a faster computer?

Comment: I suggest to download NTLite. It will convert the ESD to WIM and on top has a graphical interface with all the settings so tweaking is easy. No more text editing, all inside a nice GUI. Save the config to a file, so you can slip stream the same settings when a new windows build comes out.

Comment: https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/winreducer_esd_wim_converter.html

Comment: @Moab Thank you very much! Nlite worked and helped me so much!

Comment: @RunningChild LPChip recommended that program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do, I recommend downloading NTLite. It converts the ESD to WIM and then allows you to remove or tweak windows before it is installed. You can slipstream windows updates if you want, configure partitions, embed a registration key, and more.

And best of all, its all in a GUI, so no more text file editing and praying for the best.

Once you have a working config, you create an ISO, then use rufus with MBR / BIOS-CME/UEFI on NTFS to push that ISO to a usb stick, and you can use it on pc's with UEFI and secure boot on and it will work.

Finally, it automatically stores your settings in a config file, so you can easily create a new stick when windows releases a new version of windows.

Answer (score -1):

You'd better to have the iso file Windows 10 directly without using Media Creation tool. original ISO file has install.wim.
Go to the MS's download site by using Non-Windows, like Mac. Or modifying your User Agent as non Windows. Google Chrome's develop mode has(had?) this function.
I believe this is the best answer.

one more thing... I wanted to show the following page.
I guess That is not what you want to do but, in my case, it helps me a lot how to avoid Error 11, and to understand dism.
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-extract-install-esd-to-install-wim-windows-10-8/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1084792)